# getElementById is not a function как быть?

Tags: javascript

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://vk.com/1i_1_i_1", true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var data = xhr.responseText;
    var online = data.getElementById("profile_online_lv");
    dannie.innerHTML = online;

  }

}
xhr.send();
```

Имею вот такой код.Хочу получить определённый текст из тега и вставить в popup.html в расширении.
Проблема в том,что не работает метод getElementById(и ему подобные),в консоли выдаёт ошибку "getElementById is not a function".
Хотя если просто вставить всю полученную страницу в popup то всё работает.`dannie.innerHTML = data;`
Как исправить? со вчерашнего дня голову ломаю,100 раз уже переписывал этот метод)

Comment: вы вставьте свой текст в скрытое поле , чтоб он стал элементом дома, а потом уж просите найти по id

Comment: @splash58 Не совсем понял,какой именно текст и в какое скрытое поле.(Простите если туплю).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрытое поле в html:

```
<div style='display: none' id='example'>

</div>
```

Вставляем информацию, что вы получили:

```
if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var data = xhr.responseText;
    var example = document.getElementById('example');
    example.innerHTML = data;
    var online = document.getElementById("profile_online_lv");
    dannie.innerHTML = online;    
  }
```

Должно сработать

Comment: точно,сама "data"хранит лишь ссылку ,а не сам документ.Такие основы забываются :с
Правильно хоть я ошибку-то понял?

Comment: Да, и к тому же методы get... применяются только для DOM узлов

Comment: @ThreegunD, в данном случае `data` это строка, а не ссылка/документ

Comment: @АлександрБондаренко, можно и не иметь див в разметке, а просто создать его при получении данных

Comment: @АлександрБондаренко,теперь я совсем запутался.
Разве мы запросом не получаем полнстью DOM-документ?

Comment: нет, у нас есть только один DOM объект и это тот которым мы манипулируем, на запрос с сервера к нам приходит по сути файл который сохраняется в переменной как строка. Я тоже на этом очень путался когда изучал это)